# Using Echo to determine length of directory

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, echo

I want to use echo to display all directories in a list (not content) that are exactly 5 characters long starting with "a" and followed by 4 digits:

So for example If I'm in a directory with content of:
a23 a5134 a2913 a2341s4 a2490.txt

I should get a directory list of only a5134 and a2913 .... Is there a way to do this in the form of `echo globbingpattern` ?

Comment: wouldnt the question marks represent any character not specifically numbers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the glob pattern documentation in `man 7 glob`.

You can use `echo a[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` in this case.

Comment: Thanks i see that works, umm is there also a way to show the direcories of names with atleast 2 characters but can't start with lets say "at" .. I'm trying `echo [!a][!t]*` .. but i can't get it to work?